# Selenium: Start Chrome with extensions

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, google-chrome-extension

All.

Chrome crushing when i try to start it with extensions

I try this case:

```
                var userProfile = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("userprofile");
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userProfile))
                {
                    throw new Exception("Can't get user profile folder path.");
                }
                var userHome = Path.Combine(userProfile, @"AppData\Local\Google

\Chrome\User Data");
                    var options = new ChromeOptions();
                    options.AddArguments("--user-data-dir=" + userHome);
                    options.AddExtensions(Extensions);
                    var capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
                    capabilities.SetCapability(ChromeOptions.Capability, options);
                    Driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

And this way:

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddExtensions(Extensions);
Driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

And this:

```
            var options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.AddExtension(@"C:\Program Files\My Company\My product\ChromeExt\my_plugin.crx");
            Driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Result is:
Chrome crush.

In ChromeDriver window:

```
Starting ChromeDriver (v2.7.236900) on port 1679
[5812:10296:1206/125819:ERROR:gpu_info_collector_win.cc(102)] Can't retrieve a v
alid WinSAT assessment.
[1206/125823:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(131)] eglInitialize failed with error UNKNOWN
```

**Versions:**

chromedriver.exe - v2.7.236900

WebDriver.dll - 2.37.0.0

Chrome - 31.0.1650.63 m